# ¿Cómo crear CheckBox en pdf con iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itextsharp

Buenas tardes:

Así creo mi archivo psd. ¿Cómo agrego un checkbox que sea un campo de mi tabla sql(campo bit)?

Este es el código que tengo:

```
public void GenerarPDF(string FOLIO)
{
    try
    {
        Document pdfReportt = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 25, 25, 40, 25);
        PdfWriter writer;
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"c:\pruebas"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\pruebas");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myconsql);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter daInter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM producto WHERE folio='" + FOLIO + "'  ", con);
        DataTable dtInter = new DataTable();
        daInter.Fill(dtInter);

        if (dtInter.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfReportt, new FileStream("C:\\pruebas\\" + FOLIO + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));

            //Se Abre para editarlo
            pdfReportt.Open();
            //DIBUJANDO LINEAS
            PdfContentByte linea = writer.DirectContent;

            linea.SetLineWidth(1.80);
            linea.MoveTo(50, 642);
            linea.LineTo(500, 642);
            linea.Stroke();
            //Creamos los tipos de Letras y estilos
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            BaseFont bfItalic = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            BaseFont bfItalic2 = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLDOBLIQUE, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            BaseFont bfBold = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            BaseFont bfNormal = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cb.BeginText();

            cb.SetColorFill(iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);//COlor Letra
            //DATOS DIRECCION
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bfBold, 16);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Reporte de inventarios", 290, 750, 0);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bfBold, 12);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "No.", 450, 735, 0);

            cb.SetFontAndSize(bfNormal, 12);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, FOLIO, 470, 735, 0);// un lado u otro,posicion de arriba o abajo 
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bfBold, 10);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "nombre:", 50,700, 0);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bfNormal, 10);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, dtInter.Rows[0]["nombre"].ToString().ToUpper(), 104, 700, 0);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bfBold, 10);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "marca:", 50, 685, 0);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bfNormal, 10);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, dtInter.Rows[0]["marca"].ToString().ToUpper(), 82, 685, 0);



            cb.EndText();
            pdfReportt.Close();//Cierra el PDF    

        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception err)
    {

        Response.Write("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Asi lo adapte a lo que quiero, pero como le hago para que si en mi tabla de sql mi columna(documentos) esta en 0 o 1 osea true o false porque es bit el tipo de campo,mi radiobuton tome el valor ???

Comment: String[] sex = { "documentos" };
                //open the document for writing

                //Get direct content
                PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
                //create a Font object
                Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18);
                //create RadioButton group object
                PdfFormField radiogroup = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(writer, true);
                radiogroup.FieldName = "gsex";
                //variables
                Rectangle rect;
                RadioCheckField radio;

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dtInter.Rows.Count; i++)
                { rect = new Rectangle(40, 806 - i * 40, 80, 780 - i * 40);
                    //create RadioCheckField object
                    radio = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, "sex" + i, sex[i]);

Comment: //set properties
                    radio.BorderColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
                    radio.BackgroundColor = GrayColor.GRAYWHITE;
                    radio.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CIRCLE;
                    radiogroup.AddKid(radio.RadioField);
                    //show labels
                    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(sex[i], font), 80, 780 - i * 40, 0);
                }

Comment: hola, alguien sabe algo al respecto?

Answer (score 0):

Un checkbox en PDF forma parte de lo que se llama [AcroForm fields](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-add-new-acroform-field-pdf), puedes annadirlo usando la clase RadioCheckField.

```
checkbox = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, LANGUAGES[i], "Yes");
field = checkbox.getCheckField();
field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", onOff[0]);
field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Yes", onOff[1]);
writer.addAnnotation(field);
```

El código de ejemplo viene de este post en SO-Inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655682/how-can-i-add-text-to-a-checkbox-i-create-using-itextsharp

Vale señalar que un checkbox en PDF no incluye texto acompañante, eso hay que escribirlo como un elemento aparte.